# Intel HD4000 and yet only OpenGL 3.0 (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, opengl, mesa

I have a laptop with a Core i5-3317U CPU, which features a HD4000 chipset (http://ark.intel.com/fr/products/65707/intel-core-i5-3317u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-2_60-ghz), which normally supports OpenGL 4.1.
I installed the latest mesa version (9.2 development version) (from https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa), which I believe updated NV drivers too, as well as the kernel version xorg-edgers recommended (which is a 3.8 kernel) and yet when I run glxinfo:

```
OpenGL version string: **3.0** Mesa 9.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

Is there something else to install? Should I alter my xorg.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Because OpenGL 4.x is not yet implemented in Mesa 9.2 as far as I know. I read an [article (german)](http://www.golem.de/news/3d-grafik-opengl-3-3-in-mesa-10-0-1310-101997.html) some days ago that 3.3 is planned for Mesa 10.0 and an OpenGL 4.0 implementation is also in the works.

See also this document: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/docs/GL3.txt

Comment: Oh, ok. I believed I read that 3.3 was already implemented in Mesa's current version.